# Customizing the text in a collection_select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have a collection_select dropdown that has a dropdown of names like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:person_id, Person.all, :id, :name) %>
```

But I have a foreign key on a person that points to a group they are part of. In the dropdown I want to show the persons name and the group next to them like this:

Paul (Golfers)
Kevin (Sailors)

etc ...

Is this possible using the collection_select?

Comment: I think if you use string interpolation like "#{:name} (#{id.group})" then you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple to do. You just need to write a method on the model you're pulling from that formats the string that you want in the dropdown. So, from the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  def name_with_initial
    "#{first_name.first}. #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then, in your `collection_select` just call that method instead of calling the name, or whatever you had show up before.

```
collection_select(:post, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial)
```

Seems pretty obvious in hindsight.

Comment: Is there any way to have the dropdown populate with the current author associated with the post? I've tried :selected with no success.

Comment: If you are using the form_for form builder, it should automatically populate with the value already in the database when on the update/edit view. You'll want to use form_for :post { |f| f.collection_select ... }

Comment: I think it is really good practice to use. It just makes helper useless

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:person_id, Person.all.collect { |p| ["#{p.name}(#{p.group})", p.id ] } ) %>
```

Comment: Yeah, just tried it. Getting error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 4..6)